# Importing DB Errors: craft_resourcepaths

Tags: error, import

On the latest version of Craft, (3.7.25.1) after updating I'm getting regular errors when importing a backup into production servers during deployments.  Here is an example of the error:

```
error: The shell command "mysql --defaults-extra-file="/tmp/ewpqcugdwoke.cnf" craft3 < "/var/www/craft3/mysql_backups/backup.sql"" failed with exit code 1: ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 5894: Duplicate entry '2da4a0e' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

When I search for the entry reported in the error, in this case: '2da4a0e', I'll always find the string in the SQL file INSERT INTO `craft_resourcepaths` VALUES ... section. There is never a duplicate in the sql file so why am I seeing these errors and how can this be fixed?

Example of the import command:

```
php craft db/restore /var/www/craft3/mysql_backups/backup.sql --interactive=0
```

If I manually import the db it works. For example:

```
sudo mysql craft3 < mysql_backups/backup.sql
```

Comment: For what it's worth - I don't believe this is an issue specifically with the Craft restore command. I've frequently seen this restoring a dump with the mysql command, even after dropping tables. Only ever on this table though, so I learned a good while ago to exclude it from the dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved by Craft in 3.7.29 on 1/18/2022.

- The content in the resourcepaths table is now excluded from database backups by default.

Comment: Oh, got it, but i'm using a custom database backup statement. I need to revise that to exclude the content, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a duplicate key in there, it means that you could be missing the PRIMARY KEY on the `hash` column of your `resourcepaths` table.

[Install this plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/fix-fks) in production.

Run Utilities → Caches and clear your Control panel resources, next, run Utilities → Fix FKs.

Now re-export your live DB and try to import it again.

If this doesn't solve the issue, make sure you are importing in **an empty** database.

Comment: There is no duplicate key.  You can look in the sql file and verify that. The SQL dumps also include a drop table if exists statement so the tables are all empty. If there is a problem with the SQL file, then it is a problem with CraftCMS's export process. This doesn't solve my problem.

Furthermore I can sometimes get the sql files to import if I do not use craft's command line db/restore and instead use just a linux command line command to import. Meaning, perhaps theres a problem with Craft? Or how php is interacting with mysql?

Comment: I will try those things and let you know if it helps. @Oli

Comment: If this doesn't work, make sure you are importing in an empty database, not _on top_ of an existing one :)

Comment: Importing into an empty database is not a solution for me. Thank you for the reply but I still need to consider this unresolved.

Comment: Run Utilities → Caches and clear your Control panel resources, next, run Utilities → Fix FKs. Seems to be doing the trick for me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing this issue as well, specifically with the `resourcepaths` table. I had to do some nonsense with SED in order to get this working.

This is an extremely hacky solution, but here's what i did:

1. First replace the PRIMARY KEY declaration in the SQL file with a garbage column (this was easier than removing the PK declaration plus the trailing comma):

```
sed -i 's/PRIMARY KEY [(]`hash`[)]/`temp` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci/g' filename.sql
```

2. Then fix the `INSERT` statement for the table so it doesn't choke on the number of columns:

```
sed -i 's/INSERT INTO `resourcepaths`/INSERT INTO `resourcepaths` (`hash`, `path`)/g' new-haven-independent--2022-02-01-025526--v3.7.30.1.sql
```

3. Import your database.
4. Run the following *as a transaction* (it will not work otherwise):

```
START TRANSACTION;  
TRUNCATE TABLE resourcepaths;
ALTER TABLE resourcepaths drop column `temp`, add primary key(`hash`);
COMMIT;
```

As i say, this is an ugly *ugly* hack, but until they fix the issue, it worked for me.